# How to proceed with inverse Laplace of $s\log\frac{s+4}{s-4}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I have found the inverse Laplace transform of $\log\frac{s+4}{s-4}$, but do not know how to proceed

Comment: This here in the question is also multiplied by $s$ to agree with the title?

Comment: This sounds like a job for the convolution theorem: if $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ are the Laplace transforms of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, then $F(s)G(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)*g(t)$.

Comment: What is the inverse Laplace Transform of s @user170231 ?

Comment: @mjw no. I found out the inverse laplace of just the log term. Then the idea was to proceed with the multiplication by s procedure, but that did not lead me anywhere.